# How can I load an xml resource file from within an executible Jar file and save it to the folder the jar is located in?

Tags: java, eclipse, embedded-resource

I have a custom java server. It uses an external xml config file. 
I have some command line options to help the user, the usual stuff for showing a help file, setting ports, etc...

I've recently added a command to generate a default config file for the server. It's an xml file. After researching my options, packing a default xml file in the jar seemed to be the way to go, but I'm obviously missing something. 
So far my code looks like this:

```
public class ResourceLoader {

    private File outFile = null;
    private Reader fileReader = null;
    private Writer fileWriter = null;
    private InputStream is = null;
    private char[] buffer = null;

    public ResourceLoader() {
        outFile = new File("default-server.xml");
    }

    public void generateDefaultServerXml() {

        is = ResourceLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/default-server.xml");

        if (is == null) {
            System.out.println("Configuraiton File generation failed. The InputStream is null.");
        } else {

            fileReader = new InputStreamReader(is);
        }

        buffer = new char[4096];
        FileOutputStream fos;

        try {

            fos = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            fileWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);

            while (fileReader.read(buffer) != -1) {
                fileWriter.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                fileWriter.flush();
                buffer = new char[4096];
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {

            fileReader.close();
            fileWriter.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The code above works perfectly fine when I run it in eclipse, but intitially, after I export the jar file the server could not locate the `default-server.xml` file when I run the command from the terminal.
The file itself is located in a package called `main.resources` along with some other config files and the above class.

I have since moved the `ResourceLoader.class` to another package. After doing that the server seems to find the xml file in the `main.resources` package (`InputStream` is not `null`) but the resulting generated `default-server.xml` file is empty.

Again, this all works perfectly well when I run it in eclipse, it's only after I export the project and try issue the command from the terminal that the process fails. What am I doing wrong?

The above class is instantiated, and the `generateDefaultServerXml()` is called, from the main method of the server.

**EDIT:** My path for writing `default-server.xml` was slightly wrong. Now that I've adjusted it the code works exactly as expected when I run it in Eclipse. The resource is read in the correct way, and written to the file in the correct location. But it still doesn't work when I try the same thing from the jar file.

Comment: literally all of your code can be replaced by one single call : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You current line `ResourceLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/default-server.xml")` means that you are trying to load a resource named `default-server.xml` from the root of your classpath, or put simpler, from the root of your jar file. This means that xml file should NOT be in any package inside the jar file.

When you assemble your jar file and then run `jar tf my.jar` on it, do you see your `default-server.xml` file? Does it reside in some package or in the root of the jar file?

Comment: `ResourceLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/default-server.xml") ` IMO doesnt pick the file from the root folder of your jar. It picks the file fromyour src folder.   On the other hand using `ResourceLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("./default-server.xml") ` shall pick it from the root folder of jar

Comment: Certainly not. During runtime nothing can pick anything from your src folder. Src folder is usually unavailable at all during runtime.

Comment: OK, I tried both ways, in the root of the project doesn't work, InputStream is null. In the src folder it acts like it has found the file, but the resulting xml file is still empty,

Comment: @Nikem: I dont think so. If you dont bundle the xml file in your scr folder it shall give you a null pointer expcetion with `ResourceLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/default-server.xml")`

Comment: @bot_bot, have you run `jar tf` on your jar file? Do you see you xml file there?

Comment: I see it in `src/main/resources/` I moved it back there since it works from eclipse when located there.

Comment: @bot_bot You say that you code does not work when you run in from jar file. Please, look inside that jar file. NOT into your source. Into jar file that you try to run.

Comment: yes, I'm running the command you asked for `jar tf myserver.jar` the result is a long list of file paths, including `src/main/resources/default-server.xml`.

Comment: that means, that your xml file, `default-server.xml` lives in the package `src/main/resources` (which is extremely strange :) ). This means you have to load him with `ResourceLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/src/main/resources/default-server.xml");`

Comment: Finally!! Thanks :-) So now the question is: Why do I require different paths when running the server from eclipse vs the exported jar file? When I run `ResourceLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/src/main/resources/default-server.xm‌​l");` in eclipse, it fails to locate the file, the `InputStream` is `null`, but it works after I export it. The same line, but passing `"/default-server.xml"` works in eclipse but fails when I run the jar after exporting. :-/

Comment: Because your jar file is strange :) If you have resources source root in `/src/main/resources/`, then correct path should really be `/default-server.xm‌​‌​l`. And that xml file should be in the root of your jar file. But somehow the whole `src/main/resources` folder ends up in jar file, not its content only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112861/discussion-between-bot-bot-and-nikem).

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is since you are packaging the application as a jar. The procedure to call an external resource is quite different.

You need to have a folder structure as

```
root
--your jar
--your xml file
```

Your code shallwork if the application is using an `default-server.xml` file inside the jar. 
Otherwise, Replace below line in your code if you want to use an `external default xml file`.

```
  is = new FileInputStream("./default-server.xml");
```

If the output file you want at `root` location the use below code

```
 public ResourceLoader() {
        outFile = new File("./default-server.xml");
    }
```

Alternate code as per discussion

```
public class ResourceLoader {

    public void generateDefaultServerXml() {
        try {
        String defaultxmltext  =readFileToString("/default-server.xml");
        writeFileFromInputString(defaultxmltext);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //exception
        }
    }

    public static void writeFileFromInputString(String everything) throws IOException {

        try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("./default-server.xml"))) {
            everything = everything.replaceAll("\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            writer.write(everything);
        }
    }

    public static String readFileToString(String path) throws IOException {
        String everything = null;
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            everything = sb.toString();
        }
        return everything;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but my `default-server.xml` file is packed in the jar too. I want to extract it from the jar and place it in the root.

Comment: oh, i may have misunderstood this because you mentioned `external xml config file`. The problem you are facing is while generating the output xml at root location?  Is that correct?

Comment: yes. I have the file in the jar, I want to extract it from the jar and place it in the root folder (so when it's finished, it'll be like your diagram above)

Comment: Didn't work I'm afraid. It cannot locate the internal xml file.

Comment: is your internal xml file inside your src folder?

Comment: It doesn't work. This time it doesn't work in eclipse either. My code above works in Eclipse but not as an exported jar

Comment: OK, it still doesn't work when I compile the jar. If the xml file is located in the root of the project (the same folder as `src`) then it works when I run it in eclipse, otherwise it doesn't work. I get  `java.io.FileNotFoundException: \default-server.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)`

Comment: Are you sure you are using code `InputStream input = this.class.getResourceAsStream("/default-server.xml");` to load the file? because thats the way jar can access it

Comment: Positive. The server works 100% as expected when run in eclipse. But doesn't work when run from the jar file.

Answer (score 1):

consider your file located on src/main/resources  try this

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName)
```

Answer (score 1):

well as far as i can see your main problem is that you are passing the wrong path, since you mentioned the xml is under main.resources you will need to add this to the path when trying to load the file, here is a sample piece of code that should work for you

```
   Scanner sc = null;
   PrintWriter writer = null;
   try {
      sc = new Scanner(getClass().getResourceAsStream("main/resources/server.xml"));
      writer = new PrintWriter("./default_server.xml", "UTF-8");
      while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
         writer.println(sc.nextLine());
      }
   } catch (Exception e) {
   } finally {
      if(sc != null) {
         sc.close();
      }
      if(writer != null){
         writer.close();
      }
   }
```